# Chrome doesn't always add file extension to downloaded images

Tags: google-chrome, graphics, data-transfer, image-editing

When I download an image using Chrome or Chrome Canary, the saved file sometimes (not always) lacks an extension.

For example, I can reproduce it with this image: https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.urbansplatter.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F05%2FGolden-Gate-Bridge-Xlg.jpg&f=1&nofb=1

But not with this one: https://www.urbansplatter.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Golden-Gate-Bridge-Xlg.jpg (this is the same image but not behind DuckDuckGo's proxy).

I seem to always be able to reproduce it when saving images from DuckDuckGo.

At first I thought maybe the content-type response header isn't set in the DuckDuckGo response and that leaves Chrome wondering what the file extension might be. But that isn't true: both links have the same content-type (image/jpeg).

To make things even weirder: when I manually add a file extension of `.png` to the file, crop the image using Preview, and hit save, something is appended to the filename (e.g. 'Golden-Gate-Bridge-Xlg-1233898474.png' becomes 'Golden-Gate-Bridge-Xlg-1233898474.png.sb-701061cc-ssTk8o') and the cropped area is stored in a separate file (under 'Golden-Gate-Bridge-Xlg-1233898474.jpeg'). This does *not* happen when I use .jpeg as extension to begin with.

So my questions are:

1. Why does my browser not always store images with an extension?
2. Why that weird behavior when cropping images? My current guess is: the file in question is 'really' a jpeg and the weird behavior is my OS coercing it back into a jpeg because I gave it a png extension. (But if it knows it's 'really' a jpeg, that brings us back to question 1.)

Comment: @Tetsujin yea I definitely already have file extensions showing.

Comment: otherwise i wouldn't have been able to tell that extensions show for some files but not others

Comment: “It’s not a global setting” where would extensions not show if I have their display enabled?

Comment: "Had you just looked at the place I asked" I did right away. And when I wrote "yea I definitely already have file extensions showing" that was the confirmation that I did. My subsequent comments and question weren't personal. Curious that you deleted your first comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP headers show no extension for the duckduckgo link:

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg
...
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="Golden-Gate-Bridge-Xlg-1233898474"; filename*=UTF-8''Golden-Gate-Bridge-Xlg-1233898474
```

So this may be a case of garbage in, garbage out.

Manually putting a `.png` extension onto the `Golden-Gate-Bridge-Xlg-1233898474` file that is actually of type `image/jpeg` will complicate things even more.